# React Native Android App Crash on Kit Kat

Tags: react-native

My app is running very well on Lolipop devices but it doens`t even open on Kit Kat version. It gives me "Unfortunately the app has stopped". 
Since it is not opening I have no clue about the problem.

Do you know what can cause such incompatibility with Kit Kat?

Here is some information about the app:
In **android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile project(':RNGcmAndroid')                         
    compile project(':react-native-system-notification')    
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' 
}
```

In **android/app/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta3'
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
The app does not compile without multidex. The error is the same on Jelly Bean. Here is the log:

FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1                                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/facebook/react/views/drawer/ReactDrawerLayoutManager                                          at com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage.createViewManagers(MainReactPackage.java:98)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createAllViewManagers(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:660)
at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.createNativeModules(CoreModulesPackage.java:63)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.processPackage(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:894)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:811) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.access$700(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:104)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:200)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:183)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)                                                                  ... 4 more

Comment: Can you share the error log

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/facebook/react/views/drawer/ReactDrawerLayoutManager

Comment: Could be because of multidex.. But not sure though. Have you tried in any jellybean device?

Comment: It would be better if you update the question with complete error log.

Comment: How many views do you have nested?

Comment: Not many nested views. The app is basically a 3 tabs with listviews and I use 'react-native-router-flux' for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading react native and react-native-router-flux to the newest version.